# How to solve system of PDEs (e.g. Navier-Stokes)?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I need to solve system of PDEs.
The system of PDEs:
[image: system]
Boundary and initial conditions:
[image: boundary and initial conditions].
I used NDSolve but have some troubles (code below):

```
eqn1 = D[u[x, t], x] == 0

eqn2 = D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] == -D[p[x, t], x] + 
   D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]

ics = u[x, 0] == sin[(2*pi*x)/5] + 2 
bcs1 = u[0, t] == u[5, t] == 2
bcs2 = p[0, t] == p[5, t] == 0 

NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, ics, bcs1, bcs2}, {u, p}, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]
I am not very familiar with mathematica and I do not understand at all what the error is.
I will be glad if you could explain to me what the problem is and how can I fix it.

Comment: All built-in Mathematica functions/symbols start with a capital letter, e.g., `Sin` and `Pi`

Comment: Have you seen [these examples](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/PDEModelsOverview.html#620187094) in the documentation?

Comment: eqn1 says that D[u[x,t],x] == 0, but then it appears again in eqn2.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that works, with a few tweaks:

```
eqn1 = D[u[x, t], x] == 0;
eqn2 = D[u[x, t], t](*+u[x,t]*D[u[x,t],
   x]*)== -D[p[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];

(*Sin[(2*Pi*x)/5]+2*)
ics = {u[x, 0] == 0, p[x, 0] == 0};
(*bcs1=u[0,t]==u[5,t]==2;
bcs2=p[0,t]==p[5,t]==0;*)
bcs1 = u[0, t] == t;
bcs2 = p[5, t] == 0;

NDSolveValue[{eqn2, eqn1, ics(*,bcs1,bcs2*)}, {u, p}, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 
  0, 5},
 "DependentVariables" -> {u, p}, 
 Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", \
{"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, p -> 1}}}}}]
```

As noted in the comments, since the continuity eqn demands that  `D[u[x,t],x] == 0` we can simplify the rest as well. Also I changed the initial conditions and bcs a bit. This should be a staring point.